# Value after apostrophe is not selected from database

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I used addslashes() to insert a data with an apostrophe, in the database, using PHP.
This works.

But when I want to select this data and display it in a drop-down, it show correct value in dropdown option but when i select and use this value it only shows the value before apostrophe, after apostrophe value is ignored.

Here is my code and query for insert and select :
insert:

```
INSERT INTO `all_item_list` VALUES ('','".addslashes($t2)."','$t3')
```

Select :

```
$qu="Select DISTINCT Item_Name from all_item_list";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{ 
    echo "<option value='".stripslashes($r[0])."'> $r[0] </option>";
}
```

Comment: Please look into [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @McAden I don't find it useful to solve my problem. I think you misunderstood what I want to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and removing slashes aren't going to help you in the HTML. You need to strip the quotes in your `input` or [html encode](http://primitivetype.com/articles/quotes_inputs.php) them.

Something like this:

```
echo "<option value='" . htmlentities($r[0], ENT_QUOTES) . "'> $r[0] </option>";
```

Additionally, please research [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as calling `addslashes` in your SQL statements is [not sufficient](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) for sanitizing user input and will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove stripslashes function would help, i think. Since stripslashes will remove the slash from the string and it make the compiler to get confused.

Example: the string is "it's me", so the code becomes:

```
echo "<option value='it's me'> $r[0] </option>";
```

which result in the only string before apostrophe.

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried what you suggest, I removed stripslashes() but not working. it only takes a value before apostrophe, like instead of it's me it take only " "  it  ".